# readdir() not give error after removing USB from system and return correct dirent

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, usb, readdir

I am using linux system.
I used opendir() & then readdir() to read dir present in USB.

If in between reading of Dir by readdir() from usb, I remove the USB from system.

But still i am getting correct value of directory from readdir() & not any error.

I know that readdir() function may buffer several directory entries per actual read operation.

So how to avoid that ?

I want to get error from readdir() as soon as USB removed from system.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Unmounting the volume, or just yanking it out?

Comment: Volume is unmounted as soon as usb is removed ..Could you please give more details about your's points ....Thanks

Comment: That's improper usage, you must unmount before removing - attempting to do so will likely trigger a warning due to the open file handle.

Comment: Hi , Actually we are using one product in which facility to unmount usb before removing it is not there.  Just like Music player with usb slot with it. User can insert & remove usb at any time , without considering about mount/unmount of usb.  Thanks .....

Comment: Hi, Can we can get usb remove event in application  by some means ? If that possible then we can break while loop ( that calling readdir) .....Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you have a faulty product.  What you are trying to do is only an issue after a mandatory precondition has been ignored.